# Software rendering concept (boundary between software renderer and gpu)

Tags: 3d, rendering, gpu, gpgpu

Software renderer must communicate (in such or other way)with GPU at least  when he write image data in framebuffer. If i will additionaly using gpgpu for calculations is my renderer still be "Software" or not? **Where is the boundary between pure "Software" renderer and GPU Renderer?**

Wikipedia said that:

> In the context of rendering (computer graphics), software rendering refers to a rendering process that is unaided by any specialized graphics hardware, such as a graphics card.

Does it mean that the only work that software renderer can send to GPU is framebuffer filling otherwise it will be not pure "Software"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the boundary is where you use the actual graphics-related functionality of the hardware (and thus the actual *"specialized graphics hardware"*, like texture filtering, rasterization, ...) to your advantage in contrast to the mere **GP** GPU features of data-parallel processing that you can (to a lesser degree, of course) find in any multi-core processor. Of course in the end everything is done on hardware, but just porting some algorithm onto the GPU, without using the GPU's graphics-related hardware facilities doesn't magically make it hardware-accelerated rendering, even if the algorithm itself is related to rendering.

Of course this is a more subjective answer (to a rather philosophical and off-topic question in the first place) and I guess the boundary is pretty loose. In the end those definitions are put to test by the recent development of GPUs into rather general-puspose parallel processors.